# C++ function crashes after second call

Tags: c++, textures, sdl-2, surface

I am creating a game using the C++ SDL2 library. My game has a status bar at the top of the screen which is supposed to update after each move. However, updating works only once. Updating again causes the program to crash.

I have done some testing and found that the program crashes when the surface is converted to a texture using `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`

Here is the function that I use.

```
//screen* is a pointer to an object that contains all screen information
//  such as dimensions, the renderer, the surface and the window object
void status_bar::update(int B, const char* E, screen* display){

    if(B == 0){    //color is declared in status_bar object
        color.r = 0;
        color.g = 255;
        color.b = 0;
    }else{

        color.r = 255;
        color.g = 255;
        color.b = 255;
    }

    SDL_Surface* temp_surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, std::to_string(long double(B)).c_str(), color);
    balanceRECT = temp_surf->clip_rect;
    if(!balanceTEXT){

        SDL_DestroyTexture(balanceTEXT);
    }
    balanceTEXT = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(display->Renderer, temp_surf); //Here the program crashes

    balanceRECT.x = B_Mid_Coord.x - (balanceRECT.w / 2);
    balanceRECT.y = B_Mid_Coord.y - (balanceRECT.h / 2);

    SDL_FreeSurface(temp_surf);

    temp_surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, E, white);
    energyRECT = temp_surf->clip_rect;
    if(!energyTEXT){

        SDL_DestroyTexture(energyTEXT);
    }
    energyTEXT = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(display->Renderer, temp_surf);

    energyRECT.x = E_Mid_Coord.x - (energyRECT.w / 2);
    energyRECT.y = E_Mid_Coord.y - (energyRECT.h / 2);

    SDL_FreeSurface(temp_surf);
}
```

I have initialised all SDL Libraries, so that shouldn't be the problem. The renderer does not disappear between the updates.
The temporary surface is declared and defined each update so that should be fine as well.

Why does this function cause my game to crash?

Comment: Maybe you should try to debug and find out if temp_surf is really initialized to something meaningful when you enter the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be something with NULL pointers. Maybe check display object pointer before SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface call.

Comment: I found that `std::cout << display->Renderer << std::endl;` returns `CCCCCCCC`. So that could be the problem, but I don't see how it does work once, but not twice...

Comment: Maybe between 'update' calls there is something changing or deleting display object. Maybe SDL_FreeSurface(temp_surf) do something like that.

Comment: I made a mistake. It was not the renderer, but the texture that returned `CCCCCCCC`. In the second call it does have an address.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it helped me the most to find the solution. I have also posted the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the crash isn't in the previous line?

```
if(!balanceTEXT){
    SDL_DestroyTexture(balanceTEXT);
}
```

It seems like you are trying to destroy a `NULL` pointer

Comment: I removed the `!` so it only deletes when there is a texture, but then the function doesn't work once.

Comment: ok, so there is something else here to be inspected; maybe some class member initialization is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. The first time the update function is called is inside a constructor of a class. This constructor takes a `screen*` object as parameter. I called the parameter `display`. However, the class itself has a `screen*` variable `display` as well.
So the first time, the parameter `display` is used, which does have a value, but the second time, the class variable `display` was used instead, which I forgot to define. I changed the parameter to `DP` and added `display = DP` to the constructor.